# Firing a Google Analytics events based on response from an HTTP Post with php

Tags: php, google-analytics

I have google analytics set on a site I'm working on, It has a form that connects to a webservice, that is being sent with Ajax to a php script. the php script sends the request to the web service, then the response is parsed to determine success or failure.

I want to fire an event tracking on the condition of success and only success. I can place the event tracker on the submit button, but we want to only track successful submissions. Any idea how to achieve that?

Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Analytic's [Javascript SDK](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html#SettingUpEventTracking) fire the event after you have parsed the AJAX response from the web service and determined it to be successful.

```
_trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction)
```